# Durandal Get Started Sample

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0

I've tried following the Get Started example from the Durandal homepage, and just get..

[image]

I've refreshed the files from the Starter app / example, and followed the Get Started tutorial once a few weeks ago, and twice again today, and just get the numbers as above, not the expected form to type a name into.

Where do I even go to start debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by pressing "F12" and opening the browser debugging console, to see if all the files have come down.  There may even be some syntax errors as well.

The [HotTowel template](http://johnpapa.net/hottowel-1-1-with-durandal-2-now-available/) by John Papa is also worth a look.

If you are just starting out with Durandal, also have a look at [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/), which is effectively the next version of Durandal.

Comment: I tried the Getting Started sample with Aurelia, and that didn't work "out of the box" so I got bored and started watching some ASP.Net MVC videos of pluralsight, and following the example out of a mate's book. So far it's all working fine.